# Ideas for a Talk

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm trying to think of a suitable topic for a math talk.  I'll have 15 minutes to present, and the audience is math grad students of all different specialties.  My talk should be accessible to any math grad student.  I'd like to find a topic that is surprising and has some mathematical depth yet isn't too dense.  It can be any type of math, but I prefer analysis, dynamical systems, and probability.  One topic I'm considering is a function from $\textbf{R}$ to $\textbf{R}$ which is surjective on every nonempty open interval in the domain, but the proof isn't too interesting.  Any other ideas for a topic?

Comment: 15 minutes is a *very* short time... One thing that comes to mind is Furstenberg's topological proof of the infinitude of primes. (The result itself isn't very surprising of course, but the proof is sweet!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your interest in real analysis and probability, you should try probabilistic approach to proving the Weierstrass Approximation theorem.

You can start here: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seeger/522/fejer.pdf

"You betcha!"

Comment: I'm checking it out, but I'm a little skeptical if I can fit a presentation for a general audience into 15 minutes.

Comment: @BlueJay Oh honey don't worry you will be able to do it in 15 minute there is no problem. And if you run out of time then what can I say, you are taking graduate school advice from Sarah Palin after all

Answer (score 0):

[Schramm–Loewner evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution). You can give a basic overview of this topic.

Comment: In 15 minutes? To, say, algebraic geometry grad students?

Comment: @Did   When I was a grad student I had to regularly give talks about my research of about that length to people who were totally unfamiliar with the subject matter.

Comment: Many of us did. But on SLE?

Comment: @Did In physics we can do that easily, the talks you just prepare sheets with nice pics and tell about spectacular results. The main effort is in trying to explain what the main results are, you can often do that without invoking most of the math needed to get there.

Comment: Right, I assumed that "suitable topic for a math talk" was referring to... a math talk. But if one wants to show nice pictures and to throw words around such as "criticality" and "universality class", then SLE is not a bad choice.

Comment: @Did That's how we do it in physics, when I visited a math conference a long time ago, I presented my talk that way while most other participants wrote equations on the blackboard, more or less copying what was in the conference proceedings :) .